# Cortana popup prevention

Tags: windows-10, cortana

After riding the bus into work this morning, I logged into my computer and there was a popup telling me about "Cortana Traffic." And the most negative response I could give was "Not now."

I obviously want to disable all such things but still allow my computer to work. Short of switching away from Windows, is it possible?

Comment: Can you disable Cortana?

Answer (score 2):

You may turn off Cortana messages about specific subjects through
*Cortana > Cortana's Notebook > interests*.

You may also disable part or all of Cortana notification through
*Settings > System > Notifications & Actions*,
where you may disable all notifications (somewhat drastic).

You may also, under *Get notifications from these senders*, click Cortana
to limit Cortana notifications.

For example, you can choose to hide the notification banners but still
allow them to appear in Action Center, turn off sounds for Cortana notifications,
or prioritize how they’ll appear in Action Center.